# App deployement Failed, invalid pointer error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing window phone 8 apps since November 2013 on window 8 pro. I am using window phone 8 emulator to test my apps. But from last one week every time I want to start emulator. the emulator takes 3, 4 minutes to show "**The Window Phone os is Starting**".
 when I end the emulator there is pop up appear says "**There is App deployment errors**".
in out put window i saw `invalid pointer error`. I stuck here searching Google a lot. but can't find an answer i need.

#### What Have I tried

- disable hyper-V from windows feature, restart computer and Enable Hyper-V. But not worked.
- Change no of CPU from  2 to 1. this also doesn't work.
- Disable my antivirus so that it can't stop Hyper-V to create VM. and start WP8 emulator

I am able to create VM. but unable to start window phone 8 emulator. I found only a few solutions out there. I tried everything I found But doesn't seems to solve problem. Anyone here for any suggestion what should I do to work my emulator again. Also I can't find why this error occur.

### Update:-

anyone please answer or please suggest me what to do. should I update my sdk to 8.1? than this problem will resolved or not?

Comment: Can you create another sample WP project and try to deploy that to the emulator? Does it work? (To see if it's project specific or an emulator issue) Also -- did you try switching to a different emulator?

Comment: I tried to develop 14 projects in differant way(html5 app, xna game). but emulator won't start. it's an emulator issue. one thing i am able to deploy window store project.

Comment: Have you tried to [reinstall/update emulators](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41559)?

Comment: nop @Romasz, I think there should be a solution without reinstaling emulator. one question if I install WP 8.1 sdk will it replace totally the WP 8 Emulator or the problem still continuous .

Comment: @VikasRana AFAIK when you install WP8.1 SDK, you will get additional emulators 8.1 beside the old ones.

Comment: what if uninstall visual studio 2012 and intall visual studio 2013r2 with WP emulator 8.1 or should i continue visual studio 2012 and test apps on real device(window phone)?

Comment: @VikasRana When you ununstall VS2012 and install VS2013r2 then you will have only WP8.1 emulator. As 8.1 has backward compatibility then it will run 8.0 apps. If you plan to uninstall VS2012, then maybe try first to update only emulators (from the link I've posted above).

Comment: @Romasz VS2013 contains WP 8.1 emulator as well as WP 8 emulator when installed on win 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Hyper-V can result in a somehow fcked up configuration of the network profiles or VM Settings. I would recomend either deleting all Network Configurations in Hyper-V and all VMs OR reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Danial I think Reinstalling is the last option left.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing center -> Change adapter settings. You should see a vEthernet(Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch). See that this is enabled. That should do the trick.

Comment: I check Adapter setting for v-Ethernet it is enable and showing an unIdentify network. doesn't work?

Comment: Have you checked this link for possible culprits ? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b06cc9f2-aa5e-4cb3-9df1-0c273e1dfd68/wp8-emulator-xde-troubleshooting-tips?forum=wptools

Comment: Another try would be to delete those adapters via Hyper-V manager (virtual switch manager). Running the Emulators again will add and configure them again. Make sure anti-virus software etc. are disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error once, i just cleaned the xap file and rebuilded it.

1. Build > Clean
2. Build > Rebuild

Good luck! :D

Comment: Sorry Bachir but it doesn't work for me. I once work in android and there we use clean project to clean a single project. but here the problam is with emulator not with single project.

Answer (score 1):

if you are deploying on device and you have old version of your app which you have deployed previously then you must remove that first,then deploy new one it will not cause you "App deployment errors" and if emulator is taking time its normal as sometimes it happens, you can just close it and again have a try.

Comment: was this answer useful?